# Android архитектура приложения с сервисом, поддерживающим постоянное соединение по блютус

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

НЕ могу понять как лучше организовать приложение. Задача такая: постоянно мониторить состояние устройства по BT, иногда переходить в режим монитор плюс конфигурация устройства. Плюс приложение должно опрашивать BT устройство и в свернутом состоянии.

Как я решил это реализовать:
Сервис устанавливает соединение по блютус с девайсом и в одном потоке постоянно разгребает входящий "инпутстрим"*. Приложение обращается к сервису и в еще одном потоке сервис возвращает самое актуальное значение на данный момент**. Т.е хранение полученных данных происходит в сервисе.

Но собственно есть пара ложек дегтя помеченные *.

1) * разгребая поток я сталкиваюсь с тем, что из-за интенсивного обмена данными я начинаю парсить  данные, которые пришли ко мне минут так 15 назад... (на слабом аппарате) Как с этим бороться хз... Пока думаю уменьшить объем пересылаемой информации, хотя и думаю что не получится...

2) ** когда я пытаюсь внутри одного задания в сервисе (поток) присвоить значение public String (в сервисе, "выпарсенное" значение из инпутCтрима BT)  - сервис падает. Не говоря уже о том, что хотелось бы еще это строку отослать в другом потоке в приложение, когда оно запрашивает актуальное состояние устройства. В идеале бы хотелось бы отсылать массив. Пока тесты я отсылаю один параметр в строке.

Собственно, тут у меня уже закрадываются мысли, что моя организация не верная. Может быть надо пересылать все сразу в приложение не собирая данные в сервисе, а уж приложение будет разбираться?  Но как тогда парсить данные из потока?

П.С.
Это мое первое приложение на Java поэтому полный капец.

Comment: На самом деле у вас довольно нормальная реализация для ваших нужд и решение по уменьшению объёма пересылаемых данных довольно проавильное, что же поводу присвоения переменной String и падения приложения, то не могли бы вы уточнить, где эта переменная находится (где объявлена). Если она объявлена в одном потоке, а вы пытаетесь из другого к ней достучаться, то норма, что падает. Если вы хотите иметь доступ из всех потоков к одной переменной, то объявите её глобальной и допишите модификатор **volatile**. Что по поводу работы сервиса при свёрнутом приложении,то погуглите Android Service background

Comment: Спасибо! Попробуем (volatile). 

А из сервиса, который работает в бекграунде можно отправить, что либо в приложение без запроса со стороны приложения?

Comment: Можно, почитайте тут **http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/384199/Как-организовать-передачу-данных-из-service-в-activity**

Comment: Т.е. "биндя" сервис я его "бекграундность" не сломаю? 

Сейчас буду осваивать 2d графику - рисовать "дашборд" \0/ И учиться швырять массивы в сервис, а не строки))

Спасибо! Я прямо счастлив!))